# ASP.NET MVC 5 POSTed image fails to display on retrieval

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My apologies in advance for the noobish question. I am very new to web development.

Basically, My users can have a profile picture. When the user edits their profile picture, it will be saved to ~\App_Data\Profile_Pictures{user id}.{extension}. This is working great. I reformat the profile picture url string when returning it to the client, so it uses forward slashes. This is working well too.

In the image tag of the view:

```
<img src=@Model.ProfilePictureUrl id="profileImage" />
```

[Inspecting the HTML, the src attribute is correct, but the image doesn't load.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZrY9.png)

I will paste the involved code segments, although I don't think it's necessary for the solution. Sorry for the cringe-worthy code. Just trying to get it working:

```
 [Authorize]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private ApplicationSignInManager _signInManager;
    private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;
    private readonly IDataRepository _dataRepository;
    private readonly string _profilePicDir = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ProfilePicSaveDirectory"];
    private readonly string _defaultPic = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DefaultProfilePicLocation"];

    public AccountController(IDataRepository repo)
    {
        _dataRepository = repo;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult EditProfile()
    {
        var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        var user = _dataRepository.GetApplicationUserById(userId);

        ProfileViewModel model = new ProfileViewModel()
        {
            ProfilePictureUrl = user.ProfilePictureUrl.Replace(@"\", "/"),
            Biography = user.Biography
        };

        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditProfile(ProfileViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Retrieve current user
            var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            var user = _dataRepository.GetApplicationUserById(userId);

            //If it isn't the single-instance default picture, delete the current profile
            // picture from the Profile_Pictures folder
            if (!String.Equals(user.ProfilePictureUrl, _defaultPic))
                System.IO.File.Delete(Server.MapPath(user.ProfilePictureUrl));

            // Create a profile picture URL to save to.
            // This will map to App_data\Profile_Pictures\{User ID}.{File Extension}
            // Set the new file name to the current user's ID
            var profilePicUrl = _profilePicDir + userId +
             "." + BcHelper.GetFileExtension(model.ProfilePicture);


            // Save the profile picture and update the user's
            // ProfilePicUrl property in database
            model.ProfilePicture.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(profilePicUrl));
            user.ProfilePictureUrl = profilePicUrl.Remove(0,1).Replace(@"\", "/");

            // Save the user's biography
            user.Biography = model.Biography;

            _dataRepository.UpdateProfile(user);

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Groups");
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `App_Data` is a special folder (for database etc). You cannot serve content from there. Place you images in another folder (say `Images`)

Comment: I will try this! Thank you very much Stephen!